# NullReferenceException on *setting* value in ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm at my wit's end here.  I keep getting a NullReferenceException on the following line of code:

```
  ViewBag.PaypalError = "we were unable to retreive your cart.";
```

I know it's that line - I added some code elsewhere in the file which caused it to get a new line number, and the line number in my error changed to follow it.  I know ViewBag is not null, because I specifically inserted an `if (ViewBag == null)` test before it.

To make matters weirder, I have code to send an email when execution enters the logic that leads to the above statement.  That email never gets set, yet this line of code, which happens afterwards, throws an exception, and I get the email from the try/catch block that catches it.

I know I should probably just eschew ViewBag, and I have some ideas for refactoring the code to not need it here, but none of that tells me where this exception is coming from.

Any ideas?  Tests to try?

---

Edit:
Here's the rest of the code.  It's definitely not code I'm proud of, but it ought to work...

```
    public ActionResult PaypalConfirmation(string token, string payerID)
    {
        try
        {

            Cart cart = GetCurrentCart();
            if (cart == null)
            {
                                    // I never get this email.
                SendEmail("Paypal confirmation with null cart", "Token: " + token + ".<br><br>", requestData: Request);
                if (token != null && token != "")
                {
                    var tempCart = Cart.GetByAlternateOrderNumber(token);
                    if (tempCart != null)
                    {
                        cart = tempCart;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.PaypalError = "we were unable to retreive your cart.";
                        return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ViewBag == null)
                    {
                        SendEmail("VIEWBAG WAS NULL", "Token: " + token + ".<br><br>", requestData: Request);
                        return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Line which errors
                        ViewBag.PaypalError = "we were unable to retreive your cart.";
                        return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
                    }
                }
            }

            // More execution code here, including the "Everything worked" return.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                var isNull = "";
                if (ViewBag == null) isNull = "ViewBag was null!<br><br>";
                SendEmail("Crash in Paypal Payment", isNull + ex.ToString(), requestData: Request);
                return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                SendEmail("Crash in reporting Paypal Crash!", ex.ToString() + "<br><br>---------------------<br><br>" + ex2.ToString());
                return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Email from the catch block:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Website.Controllers.CartController.PaypalConfirmation(String token, String payerID) in C:#############\Website\Controllers\CartController.cs:line 137
>
> Timestamp: 3/6/2012 10:43:13 AM
>   IP: #############
>   URL Requested: /Cart/PaypalConfirmation?token=EC-10L01937X56050826&PayerID=############
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2

Comment: Could you add a few lines before and after that line to the question for reference?

Comment: Can you show your code with in try catch block?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Thanks for asking. I had intended on including it, but forgot. Here it is.

Comment: Step through your code to see what exactly is throwing that error.  `ViewBag` is a `ControllerBase` property.

Comment: @Shark I can't reproduce it in my development environment, and I can't step through it in the live environment.

Comment: Instead of mailing yourself ex.ToString(), have you tried emailing yourself ex.StackTrace?

Comment: @Bobson Could you log a stack trace from the Exception?

Comment: If it only repros in your production environment, can you confirm that you have the MVC 3 dll (ViewBag was added in 3) there?

Comment: @danludwig - Doesn't ToString() include the Message, the StackTrace, and everything else?  I'll include the email I get.

Comment: @bhamlin - We use ViewBag successfully elsewhere in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this is coming from ViewBag being null. When you add or remove lines, it changes the line numbers of everything below it. So it could have been any code below what you changed. If the new code required you to add a new `using` statement to the class, it could have changed every line number in the output bytecode.

Have you tried using email as a form of logging instead of just exception catching? For example, what happens when you try this? Not sure whether the `ex.Source` property would help?

```
public ActionResult PaypalConfirmation(string token, string payerID)
{
    var message = "Trying to confirm paypal.";
    SendEmail(message, message);

    try
    {
        message = "Getting current cart.";
        SendEmail(message, message);

        Cart cart = GetCurrentCart();

        message = cart == null
            ? "Current cart is null."
            : "Current cart is not null.";
        SendEmail(message, message);

        if (cart == null)
        {
            if (token != null && token != "")
            {
                message = "Getting temp cart by alternate order number.";
                SendEmail(message, message);

                var tempCart = Cart.GetByAlternateOrderNumber(token);

                message = "Getting temp cart by alternate order number.";
                SendEmail(message, message);

                if (tempCart != null)
                {
                    message = "Temp cart is not null";
                    SendEmail(message, message);

                    cart = tempCart;
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "Temp cart was null.";
                    SendEmail(message, message);

                    ViewBag.PaypalError = "we were unable to retreive your cart.";

                    message = "ViewBag.PayPalError set, returning view.";
                    SendEmail(message, message);

                    return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Setting ViewBag.PayPalError message.";
                SendEmail(message, message);

                // Line which errors
                ViewBag.PaypalError = "we were unable to retreive your cart.";

                message = "ViewBag.PayPalError set, returning view.";
                SendEmail(message, message);

                return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
            }
        }

        // More execution code here, including the "Everything worked" return.
        message = "Executing more code.";
        SendEmail(message, message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SendEmail(ex.GetType().Name + " caught", ex.Source);
        return View("~/Views/Error/PayPal.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've kindof tried that - there's supposed to be an email I get before it reaches that line that I don't get.  There's a comment on that line.  I haven't tried it as a built-up/replaced string, though.  I'll switch to that method, and see if it helps.

Comment: I've finally had the chance to implement this type of logging, and I haven't seen this error since. Whether that means I accidentally changed something which fixed it as part of this, or whether that means that one of our other changes to Paypal eliminated the problem I don't know.  Either way, this was a good answer.

Comment: Just to follow up, using this type of logging (plus a lot of manual null checks), I managed to isolate the problem.  Turns out, the line numbers being reported in the error were consistently about 5 lines off of the actual lines having problems.  Thanks again for redirecting my thinking!